# Disable the #DEN suffix in MS VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm working with some small (double) numbers in my code, and I need to see all significant digits in the GUI during debug. I can see them fine in the terminal window when manually printing using:

```
printf("%*.16e ",value);
```

Outputs:

```
1.1743571567901844e-309
```

However, during debug with MS Visual Studio 2008 using the GUI to mouse-over the variable name (or view it in the watchlist), the added #DEN suffix obstructs the view of the least significant bits:

```
1.174357156790e-309#DEN
```

Is there a way to disable that or am I stuck writing printf statements for everything?

Comment: That number doesn't have 16 significant digits.  Why are you interested in random numbers?

Comment: I'm running the same code in MATLAB, and comparing the results exactly. I need this to compare the values and see if they're different because of bugs or roundoff.

Comment: It makes little sense to hope that random numbers repeat well.  Do look up the meaning of "denormal floating point values".  First google hit is good.

Comment: So is Visual Studio intentionally obstructing the view of the lowest decimals because they don't actually exist, since leading zeros have been inserted? If that is the case, where are those last 4 digits ("1844" in the example above) actually coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this will work, but you can try using one of the `e`, `f`, or `g` [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the Watch or QuickWatch window.  For example, try typing this into a line in the Watch window:

```
value,f
```

This definitely won't work for mousing over variables in the source code, however.

Comment: That almost worked, it's only showing 7 significant figures though.